# Try/Finally block vs calling dispose?

Tags: c#, try-catch, dispose, using, streamwriter

Is there any difference between these two code samples and if not, why does `using` exist?

```
StreamWriter writer;
try {
    writer = new StreamWriter(...)
    writer.blahblah();

} finally {
    writer.Dispose();
}
```

vs:

```
using (Streamwriter writer = new Streamwriter(...)) {
    writer.blahblah
}
```

I mean in the second example you really should be putting it in a try block anyway so adding the finally block really doesn't use much more effort. I get that the entire thing might be encompassed in a bigger try block but yeah, just seems superfluous to me.

Comment: _"you really should be putting it in a try block anyway "_ Why? You could allow any exceptions to bubble up to the top of the stack and leave a clear message and stack trace in a log.

Comment: The same could be said about `foreach`, which is just a somewhat more concise version of calling the iterator methods and properties.

Comment: Your try/finally sample is defective, the using(){} block will work correctly.

Comment: I keep hearing that when an exception throws during execution of Dispose method, the `Using` statement doesn't seem to be useful in par with `Try-Finally` block. I also see [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx) article saying the same with a WCF client.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There're *some issues* with your code. Please, **never** write like this (put **using** instead), and *that's why*:

```
StreamWriter writer;
try {
    // What if you failed here to create StreamWriter? 
    // E.g. you haven't got permissions, the path is wrong etc. 
    // In this case "writer" will point to trash and
    // The "finally" section will be executed
    writer = new StreamWriter(...) 
    writer.blahblah();
} finally {
    // If you failed to execute the StreamWriter's constructor
    // "writer" points to trash and you'll probably crash with Access Violation
    // Moreover, this Access Violation will be an unstable error!
    writer.Dispose(); 
}
```

When you put `using` like that

```
  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(...)) {
    writer.blahblah();
  }
```

It's equal to the code

```
StreamWriter writer = null; // <- note the assignment

try {
  writer = new StreamWriter(...); 
  writer.blahblah();
}
finally {
  if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, writer)) // <- ... And to the check
    writer.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: why used `Object.ReferenceEquals(null)` instead of just `!=null` ? here answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51795257/2377343

Comment: @T.Todua Why `!=null` instead of just `writer?.Dispose()`? The answer to my question is the same as it is to yours: The language evolves. Especially the over 6.5 years since the Dmitry wrote his answer ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't using `using() {}` put the `new` statement outside the top of the `try`, thus avoiding the possibility of `null`?  In any case, I'm not sure how the possibility of nasty recursion during `==` operator overloading has anything to do with my normal coding practices of whether to use `x == null` or not.  It should always be obvious that operator overloading is dicey and probably unnecessary in just about all cases.  Too much sugar isn't good for you, even "syntactic sugar".

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any difference between these two code samples

Yes, `using` checks for `null` before calling `Dispose` (i.e. the actual code it is expanded to introduces a null check).

> why does using exist?

Because the code is more concise. Just a syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 6):

What you've written is pretty much the pattern that `using` wraps up. And therefore that is the point of `using` to save having to write the same `try....finally` block every time you use a Disposable object.

As for your edited question

> [...] in the second example you really should be putting it in a try block anyway so adding the finally block really doesn't use much more effort

Chances are you cant (or dont want to) handle that error from `blahblah` explicitly and you just want it to bubble up to the calling code... but still cleaning up your StreamWriter resources along the way!

So you would end up with this:

```
StreamWriter writer;
try{
    writer = new StreamWriter(...)
    writer.blahblah();
}catch{
  throw; // pointless!
} finally [
    writer.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: _So you would end up with this_ --> why would you do that? `finally` won't swallow the exception, so it is not required at all to throw it explicitly if you just want to exception to bubble up to the calling code.

Comment: The OP stated that they are going to put a `try..catch` anyway, that was just a contrived example as to why you may not need to.

Comment: The latter pattern might not be useless if the `catch` block makes note of the exception that occurred, and the `finally` block adjusts its handling of `Dispose`-related problems based upon whether the original `try` block was exited normally or via exception.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **using `using` is safer than your code** - it properly handles errors in the `Disposable` object construction, and will not call dispose on a null object.

**The second difference is in code readability** - look at your example. The first version takes 7 lines. The second - only 3.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the real difference is not just in code readability. If an exception is thrown in StreamWriter constructor the "try {} catch {}" will crash with floating Access Violation; while "using {}"  will do correctly.

Comment: That's what the first paragraph is about. But I will rewrite it, since it is apparently unclear.

Answer (score 1):

They're not entirely the same. The `try`/`finally` block does not protect against silly mistakes.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(...);
try {
  ...
  writer = new StreamWriter(...);
  ...
} finally {
  writer.Dispose();
}
```

Note that only the second writer gets disposed. In contrast,

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(...)) {
  ...
  writer = new StreamWriter(...);
  ...
}
```

will give a compile-time error.

Answer (score 0):

The latter is just syntactic sugar for the former. They should do the same thing, but the latter requires less boilerplate code.

I would recommend using the `using` one as one is less likely to make a mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately, the later is not just a syntactic sugar for the former. There's a subtle difference: if, in the former, an exception is thrown in StreamWriter constructor the code will crash with floating AccessViolation, while later (that is "using{...}") will do correctly