# VS 2015 Transaction Response Times much higher than SilkPerformer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have some relatively simple transactions that run against my application like "start user session" which typically takes a couple seconds when running a VS project through SilkPerformer.  When I try to execute the same transaction using the VS 2015 performance testing tools (locally on the controller) the response times are roughly twelve seconds longer, repeatedly.

I have a transaction logger that captures the response times of each transaction so I can see them individually during the execution in VS and I'm wondering if I'm missing a setting somewhere or there is a configuration change I can make to the project because it almost seems as if the project is pacing the execution of the transactions.  I get the same behavior whether running on an agent or the controller directly so it doesn't appear to be network related.

This is a sample of the code that's executing:

```
    public interface ITestTransactionTimer : IDisposable { }

    public class TestTransactionTimer : ITestTransactionTimer
    {
        public TestContext TestContext { get; private set; }
        public string TransactionName { get; private set; }

        public TestTransactionTimer(TestContext testContext, string transactionName)
        {
            this.TestContext = testContext;
            this.TransactionName = transactionName;

            this.TestContext.BeginTimer(this.TransactionName);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.TestContext.EndTimer(this.TransactionName);
        }
    }

    public class NoOpTestTransactionTimer : ITestTransactionTimer
    {
        public void Dispose() { }
    }
    protected ITestTransactionTimer LogTransaction(string transactionName)
    {
        if ((null == this.TestContext) || !this.TestContext.Properties.Contains("$LoadTestUserContext"))
        {
            return new NoOpTestTransactionTimer();
        }
        return new TestTransactionTimer(this.TestContext, transactionName);
    }


    private TestContext testContextInstance;
    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return testContextInstance; }
        set { testContextInstance = value; }
    }

    //starting User Session
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "C:\\Path\\Data.csv", "Data#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("C:\\Path\\Data.csv"), TestMethod]
    public void smokeTest()
    {
        sUserName = "domain\\"+TestContext.DataRow["user"].ToString();
        sPassword = TestContext.DataRow["password"].ToString();
        prospectClientId = TestContext.DataRow["prospectClientId"].ToString();
        accountNumber = TestContext.DataRow["accountNumber"].ToString();
        correlationId = "startUserSession - " + obj.ToString();

        // Start User Session
        using (this.LogTransaction("t1_startUserSession"))
        {
            ChannelFactory<IAppShellService> cfsus = null;
            try
            {
                using (ChannelBuilder.mPContext(ref appShellServiceClient, "IAppShellService", sUserName, sPassword, 0, null, correlationId, false, effectiveDate, ref cfsus))
                {
                    var userSessionResult = appShellServiceClient.StartUserSession();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                cfsus.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If not then please [edit] the question after reading [mcve]. If you have solved the problem then please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer .

Answer (score 0):

The only call of `EndTimer` is in the `Dispose` method and that is not called explicitly in your code. Hence the `Dispose` method will only be called when the garbage collector wants to call it.

I believe you need to add an explicit call of `EndTimer`. Perhaps by adding a call of your `Dispose` method into the `finally` block. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703500/try-finally-block-vs-calling-dispose).